# Load key "privkey.ppk" invalid format

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server, ssh, putty

**What have I done:**
I'm trying to connect to my remote server with private key with

```
ssh -i privkey.ppk root@ip
```

But it's returning an error.
**Error message:**

```
Load key "privkey.ppk": invalid format
root@ip: Permission denied (publickey).
```

**Expected result:**
I should be able to login into my remote server with ssh key.

**Key file content:**

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: aes256-cbc
Comment: rsa-key-20181019
Public-Lines: 6
some lines
Private-Lines: 14
some lines
Private-MAC: some letters
```

**OS:** Ubuntu 18.04

(**p.s:**

1. I'm using the same key in putty, termius to login into my remote server and its working fine
2. Ansible ping cmd also returning the same result)

Answer (score 2):

My PPK was in putty PPK format I had to convert into OpenSSH format.
I converted .ppk to OpenSSH using this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/232365), now I'm able to connect.

```
puttygen id_dsa.ppk -O public-openssh -o id_dsa.pub
```